# When using "geom_histogram" there is error "unit(tic_pos.c, "mm") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0". Why

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using `geom_histogram` there is error

```
unit(tic_pos.c, "mm") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0.
```

Why?

```
p4<-ggplot(BCIcor,aes(x=cor))+geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2)
```

This showed a black bar chart. However, when I wanted to group the data by `p` to make the plot colorful, I added `fill=p`,

```
p4<-ggplot(BCIcor,aes(x=cor,fill=p))+geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2)
```

The I got the following:

```
error :"unit(tic_pos.c, "mm") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0".
```

What's wrong??

The data frame is:

```
  cor        pvalue   p 

1  0.87882370 0.049710 2       
2 -0.83041880 0.081660 1         
3 -0.12989750 0.835100 1        
4 -0.75309860 0.141700 1        
5 -0.88553450 0.045680 2
```

Answer (score 89):

You got this error because `p` values are numeric in your data frame but in this case for the `fill=` you need discrete values as bars are stacked and will be colored according to `p`. Just use `as.factor()` around `p`.

```
ggplot(BCIcor,aes(x=cor,fill=as.factor(p)))+geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2)
```