# Filled contour plot with R/ggplot/ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm having trouble plotting a filled contour plot on top of a map with ggmap/ggplot2 in R.

My data are regularly spaced lat/lon coordinates with a z value indicating rainfall

```
> head( flood )
   lat       lon         rain
1 22.51916 -105.9318 1.486188e-05
2 22.59956 -105.9318 1.735962e-05
3 22.67996 -105.9318 2.024598e-05
4 22.76037 -105.9318 2.357599e-05
5 22.84077 -105.9318 2.741153e-05
6 22.92117 -105.9318 3.182212e-05
```

After getting the base map with ggmap, I'm trying to overplot filled contours of rain

```
map = ggmap( baseMap ) + 
    geom_contour( data = flood, aes( x = lon, y = lat, z = rain ) ) +
    scale_fill_continuous( name = "Rainfall (inches)", low = "yellow", high = "red" )
```

This gives me an error of

```
Error in unit(tic_pos.c, "mm") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0
```

If I do

```
map = ggmap( baseMap ) + 
    geom_contour( data = flood, aes( x = lon, y = lat, z = rain, fill = ..level.. ) ) +
    scale_fill_continuous( name = "Rainfall (inches)", low = "yellow", high = "red" )
```

I get this plot without the actual fill.
[image]

I've been trying to follow [this post](http://editerna.free.fr/wp/?p=54) and 
[this post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/contour-and-density-layers-with-ggmap/), but I can't get it right for my problem.  I don't know much about ggplot/R, but I've been able to stumble through it so far up to now.  What does ..level.. mean?

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569489/when-using-geom-histogram-there-is-error-unittic-pos-c-mm-x-and-uni) may be related, but I can't generalize the fix to work for contour plots.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's impossible to test without a more representative dataset (can you provide a link?).

Nevertheless, try:

```
## not tested..
map = ggmap( baseMap ) + 
    stat_contour( data = flood, geom="polygon", 
                  aes( x = lon, y = lat, z = rain, fill = ..level.. ) ) +
    scale_fill_continuous( name = "Rainfall (inches)", low = "yellow", high = "red" )
```

The problem is that geom_contour doesn't respect `fill=...`. You need to use `stat_contour(...)` with `geom="polygon"` (rather than "line").

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.  Can you explain where ..level.. comes from or how it gets set?

Comment: Your z-data is binned to create the contours (1 contour per bin). `..levels..` refers to the bin number, mapped to the range of z for that bin.