# R-boxplot set to 2 decimal places

Tags: r

Can I set mean values to 2 decimal places?

```
fun_mean <- function(x){return(data.frame(y=mean(x),label=mean(x,na.rm=T)))}

goo = ggplot(dataset1, aes(x=Pleace, y=Scored.Probabilities)) +
      geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Pleace)) +
      stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point",colour="darkred", size=3) +
      stat_summary(fun.data = fun_mean, geom="text", vjust=-0.7) 
print (goo)
```

Comment: Not reproducible. Please add the extra packages you used, as well as a dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `round(x, digits = 2)`

```
fun_mean <- function(x){return(round(data.frame(y=mean(x),label=mean(x,na.rm=T)),digit=2))}
goo <- ggplot(dataset1, aes(x=Pleace, y=Scored.Probabilities)) +
geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Pleace)) +
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point",colour="darkred", size=3) +
stat_summary(fun.data = fun_mean, geom="text", vjust=-0.7)

goo
```

**Reference**: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Round.html

[image]

Comment: It occurs an error:'fun.data = round(fun_mean,digit = 2)'
->  non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Comment: @JefferyChen Post some reproducible example and try using `round` in `ggplot(dataset1, aes(x=round(Pleace,digit = 2), y=Scored.Probabilities))` Until you give me a sample dataset, it will be hit and trail.

Comment: Sample dataset :[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0zK9xcdOi1sdTBjMzZhV3Q4X2c/view?usp=sharing)

THX

Comment: @JefferyChen Please check now and accept the answer if it solves your problem :)

Comment: THX.
I have another question. If I change column "Pleace" to "Persons", it will occur error"'x' and 'units' must have length > 0".

Comment: @JefferyChen Because `Persons` data is numeric. use `+ geom_boxplot(aes(fill=as.factor(Persons)))` Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569489/when-using-geom-histogram-there-is-error-unittic-pos-c-mm-x-and-uni